# Making MVC 6 deploy on IIS on Windows 10

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-8

I'm using **1.0.0-rc1-update1** and on IIS Express it works fine, but when I deploy to IIS, I get a blank page. Nothing. No errors, nothing in the event log - this is the same problem even for a vanilla MVC6 web application, so I doubt it's my code!

I am pointing the application to the **www** folder under the published folder and I have my app pool set up for .net 4

Am quite used to getting errors out of IIS, but this is a new one on me!
Would anyone be able to help? Or maybe at least point me at some log files?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please post screenshots of the app pool settings and the website settings windows?

Comment: There you go... All pretty standard stuff - works fine for ASP.Net 4 and MVC 5.

Comment: I think the problem lies in the `.NET CLR Version` configuration piece. As far as I know (and I haven't gotten too deep into MVC 6/ASP.NET 5 yet), it runs in its own process, and you have to set it to "No Managed Code". Check this out: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @Ruslan for your help here.

The link you provided had the answer off it as a "current word around for Beta8", which also appears to be a necessary work around for RC1!!!

https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/416

Basically, the "blank screen" I was getting was actually a 404 (I got more info by adding `app.UseStatusCodePages();` to my startup.

The work around was to rename the Configure method (I called it Configure1 as per the link above) and to create a stub Configure method to call it indirectly via the app.Map() method:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.Map("/GilLecORM", (app1) => this.Configure1(app1, env, loggerFactory));
    }
```

It now works - but clearly this is a fairly big problem for the RC :)

Comment: Sorry I should say this is only when the App is not at the root of the website in IIS, otherwise it works ok.