# MVC6/ASP.NET core published to iis 404 on controller endpoints

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have managed to publish an MVC6 website to IIS, but it seems to be only serving the static files in `wwwroot`. As soon as I make a request to a MVC controller endpoint I get a 404.

What other steps do I need for the backend code to run? I see that in the `web.config` it is executing the `web.cmd` file in `approot`, but this doesn't seem to be running.

**Edit** Running the `web.cmd` directly - i.e. using the self-host ability - works fine on the server where the app is deployed.

Comment: Did you install the httpPlatformHandler v1.2?

Comment: Yes. Initially I didn't then it wasn't serving anything. After installing it did serve the static files.

Comment: This has an answer that worked for me:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113152/making-mvc-6-deploy-on-iis-on-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this (404 on every page except for root) and while initially it looked like an IIS configuration issue or a problem with httpPlatformHandler, after running `web.cmd` manually I was able to find some issues with my connection string.

After fixing these issues I was able to run the site through IIS without any hassles.